# Simplified vulgar fractions in C

Tags: c

**"How to write an algorithm that, given a number n, prints out all the simplified vulgar fractions that have the denominator 1..n"**
(I hope I could phrase it well, feel free to rephrase.)

Example: If n is 3, the output should be like "1/2  1/3  2/3"

We were talking about this question in the end of the last class. He showed us a solution and asked us to try to understand the code. Here it is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int p,m,n,i,j,a,b;
    p=7;
    m=0;
    n=1;
    do
    {
        printf("%d/%d\n",m,n);
        i=j=1;
        for(b=2; b<=p; b++)
        {
            a=m*b/n+1;
            if(a*j<b*i)
            {
                i=a;
                j=b;
            }
        }
        m=i;
        n=j;
    }
    while(i<j);
}
```

I'm new to C and just learning to code, to be honest I couldn't figure out what this code does. And it also prints "0/1", I also wonder why that is, I think it shouldn't be printing that.

Here is my elementary approach to this problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int gcd(int a, int b) // Finds the GCD of two numbers.
{
    int temp;

    while (a) {
        temp = a;
        a = b % a;
        b = temp;
    }

    return b;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++)     // Denominator goes from 1 to 7
        for (j = 1; j < i; j++)  // Numerator goes from 1 to denominator
            if (gcd(i, j) == 1)
                printf("%d/%d  ", j, i); // If the numerator and the denominator
                                         // are coprimes then print the fraction

    return 0;
}
```

"n" is 7 in both of the codes. I checked the execution times with much bigger numbers and my algorithm is faster than the other one. So I don't understand what the other code is for. Also any suggestions/corrections about my code is appreciated.

Comment: I think you are smarter than your teacher. :) The only suggestion I would do to your code is to use variable names `denominator` and `numerator` rather than `i` and `j`. The best code is the easiest to read and understand.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will definitely keep that in mind :)

Comment: Your teachers code is living up to what it's supposed to do... vulgar code!

Answer (score 3):

Your professor's code looks like it may have been purposely complicated, maybe as a learning exercise.  If that's the case, I can't say I agree with the practice.

Your approach of nested for loops is exactly how I would have approached the solution.

> And it also prints "0/1", I also wonder why that is, I think it shouldn't be printing that.

Simply put, it prints "0/1" because of this line:

```
printf("%d/%d\n",m,n);
```

The values m and n are initialized to 0 and 1 right before the do loop, so on the first pass it prints exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is better than the first paste in a few ways.  The loop over `b` is a crappy way of trying to find a common prime factor for `m` and `n`.  But it only runs to `b=7`, so the first program can print `11/121` and other non-reduced fractions!

If the loop over `b` were properly coded, it would take `O(sqrt(n))` time.  Your `gcd()` (using the Euclidean Algorithm well) has `O(log(n))` time.

Comment: By the way, the teacher's code had a scanf part where it read the "n" number but I deleted it. The reason is I'm using Code::Blocks and it gives me the execution time when I run it. If I put scanf, then I can't find out the real execution time. I know there are ways to compute it but I didn't want to add other codes. Would you suggest something to find out the execution time? Is Code::Blocks' counter a good way to find it out?

Comment: And also I would like to ask something else, is it "simplified fraction" or "reduced fraction"? Which one is more common? English is not my mother tongue.

Answer (score 1):

The other code is exceptionally poorly written. Single-letter variables for non-idiomatic uses? void main()? No comments? Nobody should be expected to understand that code, and especially not learners.

Your code seems pretty competent - it's far clearer and cleaner than the other code and pretty much superior in every way. The only suggestion I would make is, firstly, you should take in N as user input from the console, to make rerunning the program for different values simpler, and you should also comment the GCD function explaining it's operations.